# Объединение двух связей belongsToMany в одну Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, кто может. У меня есть две связи - компании продавцы и компании застройщики

```
public function companies_builder() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company', 'pivot_company_buildings_builder', 'building_id', 'company_id');
}
public function companies_seller() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company', 'pivot_company_buildings_seller', 'building_id', 'company_id');
}
```

Мне нужно сделать связь которая объединяет эти две таблицы. По типу:

```
public function all_buildings()
{
   return ...
}
```

Помогите кто знает. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд лучшим решением будет создание одной таблицы
`pivot_buildings_companies`, в которую помимо полей внешних ключей добавить поле указывающее на тип связи (застройщик/продавец)
 Тогда в классе `Building` вы сможете описать метод:

```
public function companies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company', 'pivot_buildings_companies', 'building_id', 'company_id');
}
public function companies_builder() {
    return $this->companies()->wherePivot('type', 'builder');
}
public function companies_seller() {
    return $this->companies()->wherePivot('type', 'seller');
}
```